# How can I set up gestures in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, gestures

I would like to do the following thing: scroll down with three fingers => windows presentation from all Desktops (equivalent to Ctrl+F10).

The question is "How can I do it?" :)

I have (quite) understood how to link the mouse gestures with programs (quite, because I could not even get kate start).

Although I totally did not understand how to link the fact that I want it with three fingers (3 fingers tapping is actually associated to the middle mouse button) and I did not understand how to pass the command of windows presentation.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hi, do you mean something like this: [OS X-like multitouch gestures](http://task3.cc/1068/os-x-like-multitouch-gestures-for-macbook-pro-running-ubuntu-12-10/) As you can see near the end of the tutorial, you can configure touchegg by editing the code. You can change how many fingers, direction and type (i.e  <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="DOWN">) and what action is used (i.e <action type="SEND_KEYS">Control+F10</action>.......Hope it Helps

Comment: I do not know anything about OS X, but when trying to use touchegg I get a lot of errors of not attended token near "newline". Do you know what that mean?

Comment: This isn't anything to do with OS X, it more a description of what the package does. I haven't used really touchegg myself. Do you get this error after trying to add you gesture in? Also, How is the error presenting its self? terminal? pop up?

Comment: Ok, after a reboot the error stops showing up (it was in terminal, when launching the program) but the gestures are not working. Now I try to reboot again, maybe they will ;)

Comment: If the errors or gestures  down work, try removing it and installing it from the Software center. Just to make sure it is `~/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf` you are editing?

Comment: I installed it from repos (`sudo apt-get install touchegg`, it is at latest version 1.1.1). Now I set everything back to the origin (the file in my home was created at the first launch). After a pair of reboot it still does not work (see http://paste.ubuntu.com/5848055/)

Comment: Have you disabled the unity built in gestures?

Comment: As in the title, I'm on Kubuntu, so (fortunately) I do not have Unity ;) Although, to be sure, I have unchecked the "Gestures" in the settings immediately before installing touchegg.

Comment: Sorry, so you are. A blond moment.

Comment: Try using this. Its a GUI editor for touchegg. Try that just to make sure the config file is good [Raffarti/Touchegg-gce](https://github.com/Raffarti/Touchegg-gce)

Comment: Also there is the google code page for touchegg and setting up the trackpad [touchegg](http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/ConfigureDevices). It may also help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9534/discussion-between-biggjj-and-dadexix86)